# Error handling in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Is it possible to know the line no. at which an error occurred inside an oracle or SQL server stored procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle you can use
`DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK` to get the error stack and
`DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK` to get the call stack.
Both return a varchar2(2000).
A nice example of the usage is here http://psoug.org/reference/exception_handling.html in Dan Morgans library.
There is a lot of info available and line numbers are amongst them.

Comment: You might also need FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE is the error is caught in an exception handler

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can catch all of the attributes of the error.

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- Generate a divide-by-zero error.
    SELECT 1/0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH;
GO
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Better yet, create an error table and a stored procedure to insert these values into the table. Then execute the stored procedure in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server it will give you the line in the message tab when you run the proc from SQL Server Management Studio

For example, if you have this proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prTest
AS
SELECT 1

SELECT 2

SELECT bla FROM SOMETABLE


SELECT 3

GO
```

and you run it like this

```
EXEC prTest
```

you get this error message

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   prTest, Line 7 Invalid object name
>   'SOMETABLE'.

Comment: thanks a lot for the sql server explanation. i have not seen line numbers in oracle error messages though

Answer (score 0):

In your procedure you'll need to catch the exception.  You can even send the exception to an error log table.  How fun is that!  Or, you could just DBMS_OUTPUT the message, but it might be pretty long.  DBMS_OUTPUT has a limit on message sizes.  Default is 20000 characters.

You can even create custom [exceptions](http://myhowto.org/databases/44-using-custom-exceptions-in-oracle-plsql/).

You'll first need a variable

```
EM VARCHAR(2000);
```

Then this at the end of your procedure.

```
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      EM := substr(SQLERRM, 1, 2000) ;
      ROLLBACK;
      INSERT INTO ERROR_LOG(ERROR_TIME, PROC_NAME , ERROR_MSG)
      VALUES(SYSTIMESTAMP , 'PKG.get_stuff', EM);
      COMMIT;
      RETURN NULL;
```